# mapping 1 account to multiple opportunities

Tags: opportunity, account

I want to get multiple opportunities output with single associated account.

Comment: Please provide more information.where and how do you want it?

Comment: I just want to query multiple opportunities for an account and output them in developer console

Comment: something like this:

Comment: Map<id, List<Opportunity>> opportunityMap = new Map<id, List<Opportunity>>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SOQL and a for loop to achieve this.

The code  would look something like this:

```
Id accountId = 'xxxx';
List<Opportunity> opps = [ Select Id, name from Opportunity limit 100]; //or some other criteria to limit the result

Map<Id, List<Opportunity> > accountIdOppsMap = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
// loop through the opps
for ( Opportunity opp : opps) {
   if (accountIdOppsMap.get(opp.accountid) == null) {
         accountIdOppsMap.put(opp.accountid, new List<Opportunity>());
   }
   accountIdOppsMap.get(opp.accountid).add(opp);
}
```

Comment: accountIdOppsMap.get(opp.accountid).add(opp);
Why there is an add.(opp) at the end ??

Comment: btw it was really a great help

Comment: The add(opp) is to add the opportunity to the list of opportunities in Map<Id, List<opportunity>. I am glad it helped you.

Comment: Yeah it helped me !! but didnt this statement add the opportunity ??
accountIdOppsMap.put(opp.accountid, new List<Opportunity>());

Answer (score 0):

To add to Anup's answer, if you're only interested to know the opportunities associated to a specific account, here is what you can do.

Say, you have an account 'ABC Consulting' with id '0019000000tc1Y5AAI' and you wanna know the opps associated to this account.

> SELECT id, name, AccountId, Amount, IsClosed, CloseDate, StageName
>   FROM Opportunity where accountid = '0019000000tc1Y5AAI'

Comment: Yeah this way could be done but I will be using trigger.new to get the accounts and add them in a SET or LIST

Answer (score 0):

```
set<string> setIds = new set<string>();
    for(Account acc : Trigger.New)
    {
        setIds.add(acc.id); 
    }
    List<Opportunity> opps = [Select Id, amount from Opportunity where id in : setIds]; 
    Map<Id, List<Opportunity> > accountIdOppsMap = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
    for( Opportunity opp : opps) 
    {
        if(accountIdOppsMap.get(opp.accountid) == null) 
        {
            accountIdOppsMap.put(opp.accountid, new List<Opportunity>());
        }
        accountIdOppsMap.get(opp.accountid).add(opp);
    }
    for(Account Acc : accountIdOppsMap)
    {
        for(Opportunity myLoopOpp : accountIdOppsMap)
        {
            // How to add the Sum of amount of all opportunities and update that on Annual revenue //field of account

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read the comment on the last loop !!

Comment: you should add this as another question. This way it is appearing as another answer on this thread. No one will ever notice last-line-comments. and to make it more clear, you must not post 2 separate questions in one post.